# Encrypting and decryption RSA (Or other asymetric encryption) on Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, security

I want to encrypt and decrypt like 200 char strings on arduino mega, but I failed to find any library/code that can do that. Do you have any experience with doing that? Thanks.

I'd like to use any asymmetric encryption
The key should be ideally at least 128bit long.

Comment: what search terms did you use? ... google returns a lot of hits for arduino encryption lib

Comment: Arduino RSA, Arduino asymetric encryption, arduino mega RSA… but I didn’t find any that supports this.

Comment: Try "public key" as a substitute term for *"asymetric"*. I see EC-related stuff that would seem to qualify as *"other asymetric"* per title.

Comment: try `arduino encryption lib`